# Is the Logical meaning of 'only if' produced by 'only' (that widens 'if')?

Tags: pragmatics, formal-semantics, logic

I'm asking for multiple languages, and use grey colour to refer to the concepts denoted by the English words.

Abbreviate Necessary Condition to NC, Sufficient Condition to SC. I already know that:

1. `If P, then Q`. (In French: 'Si P, alors Q.' In German: 'Wenn P dann Q.')
   =  `P only if Q.` ('P seulement si Q.'  In German: 'P nur wenn Q.')
   = `P is a SC for Q`.    = `Q is a NC for P`.

In the first two implications, `if` precedes a SC, and `only if` a NC.

6. Does the adverb `only` cause the logical difference between `if` and `only if`?
7. If so, then how does `only` cause this? Does `only` cause `only if` to incorporate more conditions than 'if'? I've tried to illustrate below that SC ⊆ NCC, where 'only' ∈ SC\NC.

[image]

Comment: I already read http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/2157/5306.

Comment: "If P then Q = P only if Q" This is wrong. "If P then Q" = "Q if P." "Only if P then Q" = "Q only if P". But both logicicians and native speakers pretty sure would disagree that "If P then Q" (= "Q if P") is equivalent to "Q *only* if P". The order in which natural language realizes this relation is irrelevant, so whether you say "If P then Q" or "Q if P" amounts to the same (roughly, of course fucus structure etc. plays a role). The rest ist trivial, namely that "only" makes the implication a biimplication.

Comment: BTW, this is not saying that the general natural language use of "if then" is equivalent to material implication in logic, because most speaker's intuitions say that it is not; what I'm saying is only that you can't just set "If p then q" equivalent with "*Only if* p then q" (which is what you were doing), neither in the way it is used naturally nor in mathematics.

Comment: This question appears to address the interpretation of symbols in formal logic.   That's relevant to linguistics, but isn't linguistics itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question concerns the interpretation of formal logic symbols rather than linguistics.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/40060/8572

Comment: Indeed, it's interesting to cp Ger *je*, En *only*, *ever* and everything else under OE *aen-* incl. variants, and Gothic *jabaida* "if", Ger *ob*, the question markers Goth *nu*, Lat *ne-*, privative *in-, i-*, Ger *nur wenn* "only if"; further topical would be *anyhow, although*, *also*, *but*, Ger *wobei*, *aber*, *jedoch*, etc. *insofar*, Ger *immerhin* ... Only, this is not to be confused with other uses of *only* (as in this sentence).

Comment: I'd speculatively try to assume *in-* as contrast to *ex*-* in *exclude, except, include*, given that *but only if* is most often used to denote necessary exception, though *in-* "not; in-", *un-* "not, one" can't be easily confused. Also cp *but once this became clear*, *since*, likewise *while* vs Ger *weil* "because". At any rate "only if" might be calqued from late latin, given how similar the translations are. The question then is which form was original to the Latin form (if late latin may well have calqued it itself).

Comment: Also cp uncertainty about *si*, *sibi* etc as per your own question https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/381/what-underlying-semantic-notions-connect-s%c4%ab-to-the-pie-root-se-to-own-posse/383?r=SearchResults#383 Also cp Ger *solange*, En *so long as, as long as* vs *solo* (assuming corruption *solo* > *solang*; consider that *to long for* inherently denotes subjunctive mood, ie. "pray the weather remain stable, we won't have problems", vs "so long the weather remain stable"), also Ger *langen* "suffice".

Comment: Latin.SE on ["if and only if"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2758/if-and-only-if?r=SearchResults) pointing out that the formalized notion settled rather recently, but had been used variously much earlier at least in Latin

Comment: @JamesGrossmann I don't agree. The Q is about the meaning of `if`, only if`, `only` in natural language; it's not about the interpretation of formal mathematical notation, which is assumed to be well understood by the reader and would help to understand the essence of the Q. The use of `if` and `only if` in natural language and their use by mathematicians are consistent. Suggesting a theory where `if` and `only` would have a meaning and where their composition would give the observed phenomena in the meaning of complete sentences is a topic for formal semantics, part of theoretical linguistics